# Problem of datepicker arrow key reaction in antd-jalali-moment react

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, antd

My project datepicker must use jalali moment for persian language and I use antd-jalali-moment module for this. However, arrow key's reaction is wrong and antd-jalali-moment module doesn't support this. For example when you press left arrow key on your keyboard, you expect the current month to update to next month but it updates to last month. Page up and page down key like this as well.

I would appreciate if anyone could suggest a solution for this problem or introduce an alternate library or module to overcome this problem.

**Attention**: \My project base framework is react

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try adding some code, for example, refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)